# How to convert foreach loop to lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda

I have this piece of code.

I want to convert this into lambda expression. How to reach this

```
string[] MyString= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyStringData"].Split(',');

foreach (string res in MyString)
{
    if (res != "MyName")
    {
        btnshowname.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (res == "MyName")
    {
        btnshowname.Visible = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Tell me the lambda expression please and how to achieve this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
btnshowname.Visible = MyString.Any(s => s == "MyName");
```